# Ascending numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an html page with javascript and it has to sort the numbers taken from  the user from the smallest to the biggest number. I can make a pre defined array one but I can't figure out how to do it with user input. Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks! And I forgot to add that the numbers have to be separated with commas on the input

```
<html> 
<body>


<input type="text" id="userInput" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Sort</button>



<script>


function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var points = [input]
    points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    document.write(points);


}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sure you can just search online looking for the function/method javascript has to check for user input you. To my knowledge you can get data from a text field.

Comment: Are the input numbers `space/comma` separated?

Comment: Yes, they are sorry but i forgot to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `split` by `,` or any `space` characters(tabs, multiple spaces)

```
function myFunction() {
    var input = document.getElementById("userInput").value;

    if (input) {
        var points = input.split(/\s+|,/); // Split by space characteres or ,

        points.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
        });
        document.write(points);

    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong, it says "split by more than one whitespace followed by comma", so you need to have at least one whitespace before the comma. If you wanted to split by whitespace or comma, it should be `input.split(/\s+|,/)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your value an array of numbers by obtaining all numeric parts, like this:

```
var points = input.match(/\d+/g);
```

This is the most flexible way, because you can use any separator you want.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the user input is separated by space, then

```
 var points = input.split(' '); // split a string and return an array with the values
```

Answer (score -1):

`points.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a - b;
 });`

you don't need to do that. You don't need a function parameter because Javascript will automatically sort the array smallest to biggest automatically without the parameter. You just need to type *array.sort();*

Comment: If function is not supplied,  sorting will be done on string values, not numbers.

Comment: The question is about sorting values coming from the DOM. They'll always be strings. This answer also doesn't deal with actually splitting the read value to produce an array of more than one element to begin with. While it's true that numbers can be sorted with the default sort it's completely irrelevant to the problem at hand.